# Difficulty getting browserify-shim working with grunt-browserify (> 2.0.2) as transform

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, commonjs, browserify

In version 2.0.2 of `grunt-browserify`, `browserify-shim` was removed from the module itself and converted to be used as a `transform`, rather than a straightforward `option` on a `grunt-browserify` task.

The **old** version of using the shim with `grunt-browserify` would look as such:

```
'libs-dev': {
    src: [path.join('<%= config.dirs.browserLibs %>', 'angular', 'angular.js')],
    dest: path.join('<%= config.dirs.dest.dev %>', 'js', 'libs.js'),
    options: {
        shim: {
            angular: {
                path: path.join('<%= config.dirs.browserLibs %>', 'angular', 'angular.js'),
                exports: 'angular'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This worked great, and generated a wrapper around the `libs.js` module as such:

```
require=(function(e,t,n){function i(n,s){if(!t[n]){if(!e[n]){var o=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!s&&o)return o(n,!0);if(r)return r(n,!0);throw new Error("Cannot find module '"+n+"'")}var u=t[n]={exports:{}};e[n][0].call(u.exports,function(t){var r=e[n][1][t];return i(r?r:t)},u,u.exports)}return t[n].exports}var r=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var s=0;s<n.length;s++)i(n[s]);return i})({"angular":[function(require,module,exports){
    module.exports=require('i10PRm');
},{}],"i10PRm":[function(require,module,exports){
    (function(global){(function browserifyShim(module, exports, define, browserify_shim__define__module__export__) {
        browserify_shim__define__module__export__(typeof angular != "undefined" ? angular : window.angular);
    }).call(global, undefined, undefined, undefined, function defineExport(ex) { module.exports = ex; });
})(window)
},{}]},{},["i10PRm"]);
```

However, based on the (incredibly sparse and frustrating) documentation, the **new** version of the shim within `grunt-browserify` is used as a `transform`, as such:

```
'libs-dev': {
    src: [path.join('<%= config.dirs.browserLibs %>', 'angular', 'angular.js')],
    dest: path.join('<%= config.dirs.dest.dev %>', 'js', 'libs.js'),
    options: {
        transform: ['browserify-shim']
    }
}
```

and, since `browserify-shim`'s configuration is now entirely based on `package.json` configuration, my `package.json` looks as such:

```
"browser": {
    "angular": "./bower_components/angular/angular.js"
},
"browserify-shim": {
    "angular": "angular"
}
```

However, this generates a wrapper that looks like:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);throw new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'")}var f=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(f.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},f,f.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
    (function (global){
        __browserify_shim_require__=require;(function browserifyShim(module, exports, require, define, browserify_shim__define__module__export__) {
            browserify_shim__define__module__export__(typeof angular != "undefined" ? angular : window.angular);
    }).call(global, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, function defineExport(ex) { module.exports = ex; });
}).call(this,typeof self !== "undefined" ? self : typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : {})
},{}]},{},[1]);
```

As you can see, something's missing from this new wrapper; there doesn't seem to be an equivalent to the `i10PRm` export value assigned in the old wrapper. Presumably, this means I'm using exports incorrectly somehow, though I'm following the `browserify-shim` docs and it all seems fairly straightforward.

Would love any assistance or clarity regarding the newest versions of `grunt-browserify` (`>= 2.0.2`) and `browserify-shim` and how to use them together correctly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just an update for posterity's sake: I ended up ditching `grunt-browserify` and just using `browserify-shim` with `browserify` from the command-line. It works instantly with no issues at all.

I've come to the belief that the combination of the three libs (`browserify`, `grunt-browserify`, and `browserify-shim`) are all simply being updated and changed too rapidly to be able to rely upon them working together as they're updated. Ditching the `grunt` component makes the remaining two much easier to manage.

The creator of browserify-shim [seems to agree](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim/issues/40#issuecomment-40290585):

> ...in my experience whenever people wrap browserify and browserify-shim (both of which are perfectly configurable in package.json) inside a task runner, they are making their life a bit harder.

Comment: Upvoting for relevance. I swear, JS tooling is like the wild west right now. Everyone is pushing forward, rivalries are forming between camps, ghost towns already exist, people are left behind, and no will stop till they reach the coast, and then there's no where else to go.

Answer (score 10):

I struggled with this set up too, but I managed to get it working by completely removing the shim settings from my `Gruntfile.js` and letting `browserify` handle them in `package.json`. Here I'm using the shim with `jquery`, you can also see the versions I have running below:

```
// portion of package.json

"browser": {
    "jquery": "./js/lib/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"
},
"browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "$"
},
"browserify": {
    "transform": [
        "browserify-shim"
    ]
},
"devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.10",
    "browserify": "~3.44.2",
    "browserify-shim": "~3.4.1",
    "grunt-browserify": "~2.0.8"
}
```

The relevant part of my `Gruntfile.js` now looks like this:

```
// portion of Gruntfile.js

browserify: {
    bundleOptions: {
        debug: true
    },
    src: 'js/src/main.js',
    dest: 'js/output.js'
},
```

`grunt:browserify` now works as expected, by calling `browserify` but allowing it to handle `browserify-shim` by itself.

Comment: "completely removing the shim settings from my Gruntfile.js and letting browserify handle them in package.json" is the key!

Answer (score 0):

Donot run browserify via `grunt watch`, this will not reflect changes done by you in middle.

So instead whenever you change `package.json` file, run browserify task by `grunt broswerify`