# grunt browserify react requiring jquery

Tags: gruntjs, reactjs, browserify, browserify-shim

Using latest node and Grunt 0.4.x, react 0.10.x

What to via Grunt execute browserify on React JSX files that have requires on jquery in them:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

Tried moving the shim transformation into the **package.json** after reading [about a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019194/difficulty-getting-browserify-shim-working-with-grunt-browserify-2-0-2-as-tr).  Have the following at the bottom of my **package.json** file:

```
  "browser": {
    "jquery": "./bower_components/jquery/jquery.min.js",
    "bootstrap": "./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": {
      "exports": "$"
    },
    "bootstrap": {
      "exports": "bootstrap",
      "depends": [ "jquery:$" ]
    }
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [ "browserify-shim" ]
  }
```

Can't get it browserify to resolve on a simple JavaScript file (with just "var $ = require('jquery');) from Grunt.  **Gruntfile.js** has:

```
browserify: {
  options: {
    debug: true
  },

  src: ['src/views/**/*.js'],
  dest: 'build/javascript/client.js'
},
```

Running Grunt gives the following error:

```
Error: module "jquery" not found from "D:\\development\\projects\\Prenotes\\src\\views\\dummy.js"
```

If and when I get this working then I assume "reactify" can be added to the transform array in the **package.json**.

Answer (score 3):

I put "reactify" in my transform segment in the **package.json** and redid the Grunt browserify as:

```
browserify: {
  dist: {
    files: {
      'build/bundle.js' : ['src/views/**/*.jsx']
     }
  }
},
```

Without the "dist" browserify wouldn't run properly.

This got the shim to work but reactify wouldn't run, so I ended up switching back to grunt-react plus pulled the transform logic back into the **Gruntfile.js** (which just feels better).

So at the end of the **package.json** there is:

```
  "browser": {
    "jquery": "./lib/jquery/jquery.js",
    "bootstrap": "./lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": {
      "exports": "$"
    },
    "bootstrap": {
      "exports": "bootstrap",
      "depends": [ "jquery:$" ]
    }
  }
```

and in the **Gruntfile.js**:

```
browserify: {
  options: {
    debug: true,
    transform: ['browserify-shim', require('grunt-react').browserify]
  },
  dist: {
    files: {
      'build/bundle.js' : ['src/views/**/*.jsx']
    }
  }
},
```

This both shims and processes the JSX.  Finally.