# Including Typeahead.js Bloodhound with Browserify gives empty object {}

Tags: javascript, typeahead, browserify, bloodhound, browserify-shim

I'm trying to use Bloodhound and Typeahead in my Browserify project. I'm using browserify-shim.

**package.json**

```
{
     ...
    "browserify": {
        "transform": ["browserify-shim"]
    },
    "browserify-shim": "./shim.js",
}
```

**shim.js**

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    'typeahead.js/dist/bloodhound': {
        exports: 'Bloodhound',
        depends: {jquery: 'jQuery'}
    }
};
```

**test.js**

```
...
var Bloodhound = require('typeahead.js/dist/bloodhound');

module.exports = function() {
    console.log(Bloodhound);
}
```

Which outputs an empty object ({}).

I've followed everything in this [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019194/difficulty-getting-browserify-shim-working-with-grunt-browserify-2-0-2-as-tr), using vanilla Browserify from the command line, but still no dice.

---

I was able to get it working by adding

```
module.exports = Bloodhound;
```

to the bloodhound.js file, but this is far from ideal. Shouldn't browserify-shim be adding the exports? I didn't see a module.exports for Bloodhound in the generated bundle.js.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this will be fixed in v0.11 as typeahead.js is moving to the UMD

https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/743#issuecomment-52412193